# diff function doesn't work with Greek letters

Tags: symbolic-math, maxima, wxmaxima

Consider the list

```
P : [r * sin(%phi) * sin(%gamma), r * cos(%phi), r * sin(%phi) * cos(%gamma)];
```

when using the `diff()` function:

```
diff(P, %phi, 1);
```

and I get the error:

> diff: second argument must be a variable; found
>
> -- an error. To debug this try: debugmode(true);

Now if I remove the `%` percent sign before the Greek letters

```
P : [r * sin(phi) * sin(gamma), r * cos(phi), r * sin(phi) * cos(gamma)];
```

it works but it shows some Greek symbols as their capital:

I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can solve it. Thanks for your support in advance.

Comment: `%phi` is a built-in constant, similar to `%pi` in that respect; its numeric value is approximately 1.618. `%phi` is the so-called golden ratio, defined as (1 + sqrt(5))/2. Looks like `phi` works OK in place of `%phi`.

Comment: @RobertDodier my apologies for the late reply. Somehow I missed the notification. So you are telling me I should do `P : [r * sin(phi) * sin(%gamma), r * cos(phi), r * sin(phi) * cos(%gamma)];`? Doesn't it seem inconsistent? What is the correct what to include Greek letters in Maxima, with or without the `%`?

Comment: Yes, I agree it's inconsistent. The main problem here is that `gamma(x)` is the gamma function which is conventionally written with a big letter. So that makes it necessary to say `%gamma` to get a small letter. But note that `%gamma`, in addition to `%phi`, is a numerical constant; it is the Euler-Mascheroni number. My advice at this point is to change the display property for `gamma` and use only names without `%`. I don't remember exactly how to change display properties in wxMaxima, but it is pretty simple. You can ask on the wxMaxima user forum or issue tracker about how to do that.